# How can I increase Firebase Authentication Limits?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently writing a project using Firebase for authentication purposes. I came into [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#account_creation_and_deletion_limits) which states:

> Account creation and deletion limits
>
> Operation              Limit
>
> New account creation  100 accounts/IP address/hour
>
> Account deletion  10 accounts/second

This can't be true right? I mean 100 new accounts per hour is quote low, right? Firebase is supposed to help projects with scaling fast, why would they limit the new user accounts so much? Can I do something to increase this limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you read the limit incorrectly.  It's not "100 new accounts per hour".  It's "100 new accounts **per IP address** per hour".  Practically speaking, there are tens of millions of unique IP addresses that people will be coming from all over the world.  They will definitely not come from a single IP address, and in practice, your project will almost certainly not exceed this limit.

This particular limit is intended to slow the progress of attackers who are trying to create many accounts in your project in order to compromise it or exceed the resources you intend to allocate per person.  You definitely want this limit in place.

If you do think the limit is going to be problematic, then you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly, as Stack Overflow will be of no help to you.